# Pronamic Info Window

Tags: plugins, customization

I am using Pronamic Google Maps (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pronamic-google-maps/) to add Google Maps to my post...I would like to do a couple of things:

1. I noticed that the balloon, or info window, has to be clicked in order for it to appear, is there a way to make it appear by default?
2. Also on the balloon, or info window, I see a scrollbar which appears regardless of how much content is being shown...is there a way to remove the scrollbar when not in use?

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just switching plugins...I am now using MapPress: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/